# Resource Dictionaries from different project throwing an exception

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a resource dictionary in a separate project called `ItemsTemplate`.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
           x:Key="TextBoxesTemplate"
           >
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="1"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I am wanting to use this accross many different projects. and I am throwing an exception when I run it that says:
 `'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.'`

so here is my implementation and what I have tried:

and

```
    <ResourceDictionary  Source="/ItemTemplates;component/Style.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
```

and

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxesTemplate}"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="2"
         Text="{Binding SelectedModel.Code}"/>
```

I have tried to change to

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     <ResourceDictionary  Source="/ItemTemplates;component/Style.xaml">
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

and

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     <ResourceDictionary  Source="/ItemTemplates;component/Style.xaml">
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     <ResourceDictionary  Source="pack:application,,,/ItemTemplates;component/Style.xaml">
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**Note:** this is .net 4.5.2

**Edit:** builds using this. but still getting exception

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="/ItemTemplates;component/Style.xaml"
                                 x:Name="SDictionary" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Im guessing that you are setting your dictionaries within resources tag? like <UserControl.Resources> then your merge dictionary </UserControl.Resources>

Comment: yes i am using the . resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(VS.85).aspx

as long as current project has a reference to separate project.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/ItemTemplates;component/Style.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Please check reference again and `Source="/ItemTemplates` or `Source="/ItemsTemplate` because in your question, you wrote is: "*I have a resource dictionary in a separate project called **ItemsTemplate**.*"

Hope can help you !

Comment: okay, I have referenced the page that you suggested  however it still isn't working. I doesn't build with ".MergedDictionaries" is that nesscessary?

Comment: If you use only one ResourceDictionary

Comment: I tryed :<UserControl.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="/ItemTemplates;component/Style.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources> and It work fine for me